# É possível fazer um POST de um ficheiro automaticamente?

Tags: php, cron

*Estou a usar o [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) para correr um script PHP. Quero fazer um teste de carga de envio de ficheiros para o meu servidor e o [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) fica encarregue disso (o servidor depois envia para a Amazon).*

Eu estava a pensar utilizar o [file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) para fazer o upload de ficheiros para o servidor mas como eu retiro as informações do ficheiro?
(filename, type, etc)

Eu vi [esta função](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133997/1817673) em JavaScript para fazer um POST e enviar automaticamente. Posso fazer isso em PHP puro?

Comment: Você quer criar um requisição via `file_get_contents ou curl` com um upload de arquivo junto?

Comment: Sim @perdeu alguém que me percebe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a ajuda da [resposta do @Math](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38960/7210) lembrei me do [Curl](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) para criar o POST.

Então comecei por criar o meu *script* PHP(`upload_test.php`) onde faço o POST do meu ficheiro(`myfile_test.zip`) para o `gravar.php` e guardo o resultado em `teste_results.txt`.

**upload_test.php:**

```
$user_id = rand( 1, 10 );

$local_file = '/my_dir/myfile_test.zip';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0                              );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0                             );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true                   );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true                             );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/gravar.php'     );

$post_array = array(
    "uploaded_file" => "@" . $local_file,
    "function" => "upload",
    "user_id" => "$user_id",
);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array );
$response = curl_exec( $ch );

$myfile = fopen( "/my_dir/teste_results.txt", "a+" ) or die( "Unable to open file!" );

$txt = "\n=> AUTO_UPLOAD " . date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) . "\n";
fwrite( $myfile, $txt );

fwrite( $myfile, "Fez upload? = " . $response . "\n" );

fwrite( $myfile, "\n" );

fflush( $myfile );
fclose( $myfile );
```

[Fonte Curl](http://www.maheshchari.com/upload-image-file-to-remote-server-with-php-curl/)

Do lado do `gravar.php` apanho assim o ficheiro:

```
$uploaded = (object) $_FILES['uploaded_file'];

$file_name = $uploaded->name;
$file_tmp  = $uploaded->tmp_name;
$file_type = $uploaded->type;
$file_size = $uploaded->size;
```

Depois foi só adicionar a linha de execução ao [Crontab](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) e posso criar as linhas que quiser para testar a carga do meu servidor.

Na linha de comandos:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Inserir a linha seguinte e gravar: (10 em 10 minutos)

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/my_dir/upload_test.php
```

[Fonte do crontab](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/crontab-every-10-min/)

Comment: Ficou mais simples mesmo, +1

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o AWS SDK for PHP - (http://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdk-for-php/
)!

Lá você consegue controlar e enviar arquivos para a amazon através do php, mesmo que seja um script rodando na cron.

Agora, para ler as informações da pasta, você pode usar a função [opendir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php).

```
<?php
$dir = "/etc/php5/";

// Abre um diretorio conhecido, e faz a leitura de seu conteudo
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Eu já tenho a API REST a funcionar, falta-me é saber como fazer um POST automático para o PHP

Answer (score 2):

Configurando corretamente o cabeçalho da requisição é possível enviar um upload de arquivo, tanto com o [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) ou [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

//post_falso.php

```
<?php

define('MULTIPART_BOUNDARY', '---'.microtime(true));
define('FORM_FIELD', 'uploaded_file');

$header = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.MULTIPART_BOUNDARY;


$filename = "c:\\teste.txt";
$file_contents = file_get_contents($filename); //carrega o arquivo falso

$content =  "--". MULTIPART_BOUNDARY ."\r\n".
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"". FORM_FIELD. "\"; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\"\r\n".
        "Content-Type: application/zip\r\n\r\n". //define o mime type
        
        $file_contents."\r\n";

//adiciona uma campo chamado foo com o valor bar.
$content .= "--".MULTIPART_BOUNDARY."\r\n".
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"foo\"\r\n\r\n"."bar\r\n";

// fecha o cabeçalho, é obrigatório usar dois traços a mais
$content .= "--".MULTIPART_BOUNDARY."--\r\n";


//Define o cabeçalho http
$context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => $header,
                'content' => $content,
                'user_agent' => '?',
        )
));

$response = file_get_contents('http://teste/gravar.php', false, $context);
echo $response;
```

gravar.php

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                  'caminho\nome_do_arquivo'. $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
```

Refêrencias:

[Upload a file using file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4003989/1342547)

[How to post data in PHP using file_get_contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2445276/1342547)

[How does HTTP file upload work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660740/1342547)

Comment: Não percebi muito bem a última parte de `$response = ...`.

Comment: @JorgeB. serve para exibir o retorno de `file_get_contents` ou caso vc precisa validar a 'saida como procurar `operação realizada com sucesso` ou `erro: ....`

Comment: Esta-me aqui a passar alguma coisa ao lado... Eu tenho um `.php` que está a espera de um POST e ao receber um POST se for um ficheiro guarda os dados na BD e envia para a Amazon.

Comment: Eu ao fazer esta linha : `$response = file_get_contents('http://teste/gravar.php', false, $context);` imprime-me o conteúdo do ficheiro gravar.php

Comment: @JorgeB. imprime o código fonte ou os valores de $_POST e $_FILES

Comment: @JorgeB. no seu exemplo o endereço está algo assim:
`http://localhost/nome_projeto/gravar.php` ? a tag de abertura do php é a `<?php`

Comment: e assim: `file_get_contents('http://localhost/gravar.php');`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18365/discussion-between-perdeu-and-jorge-b).