# Copiar o conteúdo de um Json via PHP e enviar para o servidor

Tags: php, json

É possível via `PHP` copiar o conteúdo Json de uma página (uma API que esta gerando um `json` dinâmico) como esta http://www.folhacar.com.br/frontendnovo.php/api/listMarcas e salvar em um diretório dentro do meu site "json/arquivo.json"? Pois eu poderia criar um tarefa cron para sempre fazer isso 1 vez por dia.

Caso não seja possível eu sempre precisarei acessar essa api, copiar o conteúdo, criar um `json` e fazer upload pra pasta que desejo?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38725/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-fazer-um-post-de-um-ficheiro-automaticamente

Comment: Fábio vê se a pergunta que eu coloquei como duplicata responde a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desta forma:

```
$string  = file_get_contents("/home/pasta/test.json");

$arquivo = fopen('arquivo.json','w+');

if($arquivo){
    if (!fwrite($arquivo, $sring)){
        echo('Não foi possível atualizar o arquivo');
    }
    echo 'Arquivo atualizado com sucesso<br>';
    fclose($arquivo);
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado Ricardo!